# Closest period with one time column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which contains periods defined each day on a 24 hour cycle.

```
CREATE TABLE periods (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    name varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    period_time time NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT pk_period PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

My goal is to retrieve for each period it's start and end date like this :

```
|  begin |  end   |    name   |
|07:00:00|13:00:00| morning   |
|13:00:00|20:00:00| afternoon |
|20:00:00|07:00:00| evening   |
```

I've already done a query, but i'm pretty sure there's smarter way to do this as i'm using two left joins to fill the latest period which has a null value due to it's first left join condition :

```
select p.period_time, coalesce(next_period.period_time,first_period.period_time), p.name
from periods p
left join lateral (
    select period_time 
    from periods p2
    where p2.period_time > p.period_time
    order by period_time 
    limit 1
) as next_period on true
left join lateral (
    select period_time 
    from periods p2
    where p2.period_time >= '00:00:00'
    limit 1
) as first_period on true
order by p.period_time
```

Any suggestions ?
Performance is key, as this could be integrated in inner sub-queries, and i'm not able to change table definition.

Comment: As a side note: the use of `serial` is discouraged in modern Postgres version in favour of `identity` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a window function as described in the documentation [3.5. Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tutorial-window.html) and [9.22. Window Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)s :

```
SELECT p.period_time AS begin, lead(p.period_time) OVER (order by p.period_time) AS end, p.name
FROM periods p
```

Comment: Thanks @Edouard H. , almost perfect. I wasn't aware of this approach. Nevertheless, it's still missing the last end date. Do you agree to add this statement in order to 
```coalesce(..., first_value(p.period_time) OVER (order by p.period_time))```
achieve my goal ?

Comment: Yes, in fact, I didn't see that you want to loop on the first period_time.  In the lead() window function, there is an option to define the value when no row is found anymore and which is NULL by default, but I don't see how to set up this value with the first value of the window as first() cannot be used at this place. So your proposal sounds good in order to achieve this.

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly what happened to me before suggesting this :)